# Matlab:Issues in clustering

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, dimensionality-reduction

I need to perform dimensionality reduction on a multi dimensional data set data set that has been clustered using k-means. The data contains positive and negative real numbers obtained from sensor readings of sensors placed on a haptic glove. The data is captured while representing an action say drawing letter "A" as

```
    0.1373   -1.8764
   -1.7020   -0.8322
    0.4862    0.8276
   -0.0078    1.3597
    0.9008    1.8043
    2.9751    0.7125
   -0.3257    0.1754
```

Now, my confusions are

1. I do not get any clustering for multi dimensional data using the following code

> ```
> K=3;
> load('b2.txt');
>
>
>
> data = b2;
> numObservarations = length(data);
> %% cluster
> opts = statset('MaxIter', 500, 'Display', 'iter');
> [clustIDX, clusters, interClustSum, Dist] = kmeans(data, K, 'options',opts, ...
>     'distance','sqEuclidean', 'EmptyAction','singleton', 'replicates',3);
> %% plot data+clusters
> figure, hold on
> scatter3(data(:,1),data(:,2),data(:,3), 50, clustIDX, 'filled')
> scatter3(clusters(:,1),clusters(:,2),clusters(:,3), 200, (1:K)', 'filled')
> hold off, xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')
> ```

How to rectify this?What is wrong?

1. After obtaining the clusters across all dimension, I now represent the data by its cluster labels as

   1
   1
   3
   2

and so on.

- Does this data incorporate temporal ordering of the events? By glancing it does but there are papers which say that clustering does not take into account the temporal ordering.
- I need to reduce its length. I am aware of Principal component analysis but that is used to select the dimensions and does not reduce data lenght. Is it reasonable to use this reduced format for distance based classification using an incoming test data set?

Comment: First of all, `data = b2(1:100);` seems to imply that this is a 1D not 2D clustering problem. Perhaps with some idea about what your data looks like we can help a little more...

Comment: Sorry,that was a typo. I deleted that and added few samples of the data. Still there is no plot

Comment: can you tell us what is the output of size(data)?

Comment: The size is 200     2 . Also what is the meaning of "opts" here?How many times does the algorithm run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you provide works perfectly well with slight modification for the **2D** data set (two features) you provided.

Try it as follows:

```
data=[    0.1373   -1.8764
         -1.7020   -0.8322
          0.4862    0.8276
         -0.0078    1.3597
          0.9008    1.8043
          2.9751    0.7125
         -0.3257    0.1754];

numObservarations = length(data);
K=3

%% cluster

%opts = statset('MaxIter', 500, 'Display', 'iter');
[clustIDX, clusters, interClustSum, Dist] = ...
     kmeans(data, K, 'MaxIter', 500, 'Display', 'iter', ...
            'distance','sqEuclidean', 'EmptyAction','singleton', 'replicates',3);

%% plot data+clusters

figure, hold on
scatter(data(:,1),data(:,2), 50, clustIDX, 'filled')
scatter(clusters(:,1),clusters(:,2), 200, (1:K)', 'filled')
hold off, xlabel('x'), ylabel('y')
```

This is the result:

[image]

Once again, the dataset you provided contains **2** features, so it is essentially 2D.

As far as I understand, `kmeans` clusters the data, it does not by itself perform dimensionality reduction (I await anyone else reading this to correct me). For dimensionality reduction what you really want to do is PCA or similar. Following PCA you can project your data onto the principal component axis and display the clusters in a "lower dimensional" way.

I don't actually understand what you mean by temporal ordering, but I if there is some correlation between temporal events and the features you can expect `kmeans` to classify (indirectly) according to those events.

---

Here's another example. This time the cluster size is 3. The centroids of the clusters are in variable `clusters` output above by `kmeans`.

[image]

The plot on the left shows the points in the 2D feature space colored according to *time* (the colorbar shows how the relative time relates to color). The middle figure shows what cluster points were assigned to according to a new color scale, same color scale as on the right plot which shows the position of the centroids. The point of the figure is to display the temporal regularity with which features show up.

With regard to your question about temporal ordering, it would appear that `kmeans` can uncover implicit temporal correlations in the features (if that's what you mean), as shown in the following plot of `clustIDX` versus time:

[image]

But I do not know how it compares to other processing algorithms (why it would be advantageous). I would head to dsp.stackexchange for a better answer.

---

The subplots were generated with the following code:

```
subplot(121);
scatter(data(:,2),data(:,3), 50, clustIDX, 'filled')
axis tight 
box on
xlabel('feature 1'), ylabel('feature 2')
title('labelled points')

subplot(122);
scatter(clusters(:,2),clusters(:,3), 200, (1:K)', 'filled')
axis tight
box on
xlabel('feature 1'),ylabel('feature 2')
title('clusters')
```

Second plot:

```
figure
scatter([1:length(clustIDX)],clustIDX, 50, clustIDX, 'filled')
xlabel('time'),ylabel('cluster')
box on
axis tight
title('labelled points in time domain')
```

Comment: Oh I see, the plot function was incorrect, thank you. Comment1 : I know that kmeans does not do dimensionality reduction although it returns a single cluster for the multi-dimensional data. I don't want to do dimensionality reduction but want to reduce the length of data similar to data mining applications. I wanted to use the clustered data ie. original data represented by its labels [12113...] So, with a window length of 3 was wondering if it is possible to group them.

Comment: Comment2: The next thing I wanted to know is if the data is represented by its clusters say [12113...]then does this information tell us about the underlying temporal ordering of the activity that generated the data?Is there a proof ?

Comment: Thank you for the edited version. 1. Could you please tell me the commands to plot these 3 new graphs using the colors? 2. Also could you further provide some insights into the third graph as to how the graph or the clusterIDx vs time adheres the temporal ordering? 3. Lastly,I could not understand why the algorithm iterates 14 times & explaination that since I have a cluster mean for each dimension then how come I get a single cluster label for all the dimensions?Highly appreciate your continued help.

Comment: @SrishtiM kmeans finds the clusters iteratively. At each iteration the RMSD between each centroid and the points belonging to the cluster is reduced. Each cluster has its own arbitrary numeric label, from 1 up to the number of clusters. You wrote that you would like to cluster 3 points into one centroid, so I specified that kmeans should generate N/3 clusters (each cluster will however not necessarily have just 3 points, some may have less of more points).

Comment: @SrishtiM I think you are a little confused about the meaning of dimension versus cluster. The clusters do not represent dimensions, they represent... clusters of points.

Comment: @SrishtiM As for the temporal clustering, I just plotted the numeric value of the cluster versus the time variable (which for the data I plotted is an *implicit* variable and NOT a feature). The underlying data is a sinusoid. The plot is only a simple graphical example, not more. You see a pattern of points belonging to the same cluster (or vicinal clusters) showing up with a certain regularity over time. That just reflects the fact that the data oscillates, such that points distant in time end up with the same value of the features. For deeper insight I would turn elsewhere.

Comment: @SrishtiM The functional form of the features is feature1 = sin(time*w1); feature2 = sin(time*w2);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38133/discussion-between-srishti-m-and-try-hard)

Comment: What I meant in pt2 - If I plot clusterIdX w.r.t time then will the cluster labels indicate anything about the temporal structure of the original data? In pt3 is that if (x1,y1;x2,y2;x3,y3..) is being represented to (1,2,1) etc, so (x1,y1) falls under a single cluster. What is the rationale behind this? Once again than you for your continued help. Is there any way that I may reach you through email if I have questions (sorry for being shameless about this) regarding other areas since I observe that you have answered all my questions so far.

Comment: @SrishtiM The plot of cluster# versus time reveals a temporal recurrence of features. But I'd have to look into in more detail to sort out how to extract, say, the frequency with which features recur, in a clear *quantitative* sense. I tried FFT but this was not particularly enlightening. This is a complicated problem and I'd have to research the theory more to figure it out.

Comment: @SrishtiM As for point#3, the rationale is that, in your short example, x1,y1 and x3,y3 fall close to each other in the three dimensional space, and so kmeans assigned them to the same cluster

Comment: @SrishtiM Feel free to email me at  t3hard at gmail dot com. Somewhat slow responding there though :)